# I/O operation on closed file when the file is not closed

Tags: python, if-statement, valueerror

I have written a piece of code in Python which needs to check a few arrays and ensure certain values are not in there. These values are in the form of variables which I defined like so:

```
    tempArray = "".join(map(str,array))

    dashTemp = tempArray[0:11]
    dotTemp = tempArray[11:23]
    spaceTemp = tempArray[23:35]

    dashTemp = "".join(sorted(dashTemp))
    dotTemp = "".join(sorted(dotTemp))
    spaceTemp = "".join(sorted(spaceTemp))
```

I have then attempted to check whether these values are already in existing text files that I have set up (which I opened earlier):

```
    if array in f or dashTemp in fa or dotTemp in fo or spaceTemp in fs:
        f.close()
```

The above code works perfectly fine, however it is when I change it to the following that it does not work:

```
    if array in f or dashTemp in fa or dotTemp in fo or spaceTemp in fs or "6" in spaceTemp or "o" in spaceTemp:
        f.close()
```

I am given the error "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." which I do not understand, because what I added has nothing to do with a file; the *spaceTemp* variable is the only new thing referenced. I could even understand if the error was located on the line *f.close()*, but it is not.

> File "...", line 76, in gen
> if array in f or dashTemp in fa or dotTemp in fo or spaceTemp in fs or "6" in spaceTemp or "o" in spaceTemp:
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

As I have mentioned, all three files (*f*, *fa*, *fo* and *fs*) are all open, and this works without the added  "*or "6" in spaceTemp...*".

Any ideas?

More context:

```
f = open("iterations.txt","r")
fa = open("dashes.txt","r")
fo = open("dots.txt","r")
fs = open("spaces.txt","r")
while restart == True:
    while count < 36:
        characterAdd = chars[random.randint(0,35)]
        if not characterAdd in array:
            array.append(characterAdd)
            count += 1
        else:
            pass
    tempArray = "".join(map(str,array))
    dashTemp = tempArray[0:11]
    dotTemp = tempArray[11:23]
    spaceTemp = tempArray[23:35]
    dashTemp = "".join(sorted(dashTemp))
    dotTemp = "".join(sorted(dotTemp))
    spaceTemp = "".join(sorted(spaceTemp))
    if array in f or dashTemp in fa or dotTemp in fo or spaceTemp in fs  or "6" in spaceTemp or "o" in spaceTemp:
        f.close()
```

Comment: Without more context, we can't say why `f` is already closed.

Comment: You're closing the file `f` in a loop, then aren't reopening it again. What happens when you close it then try to use it again in the next iteration? `in` here will attempt to read the file (and also moves the cursor to the end of the file iirc, which makes the file useless for reading until you re-`seek` to the start).

Comment: The `in` works fine until I include the `or "6" in spaceTemp or "o" in spaceTemp`. I don't see how that addition causes the file to act differently.

Comment: @vb4 The simplest answer is the file was never closed until you added that to the condition (if that's true, that means that that check wasn't doing anything with the original condition since it was always false).

Comment: the more important question here is, "what are you actually trying to do?"  this is probably not the way to go about it.  _why_ do you want to close the filestream?  do you have something that checks if it's closed?  perhaps just get the read values and do a test on that?

Comment: To add to @e.s., this post resembles an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please provide the background of your overall problem (i.e., (x*) and not just your attempted solution (i.e., *y*).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have tried just using `pass` instead, and this seems to work part of the time, though I think the other times when nothing happens is likely due to other parts of the code not working properly.

Comment: @e.s. and @Parfait I am trying to write a brute-force script to come up with all possible solutions to a Pollux cipher, and the purpose of the added "6" and "o" into the if statement is due to the first and last characters of the ciphertext (which are "6" and "o" respectively, and cannot be included in the spaces group, represented by the `spaceTemp` variable).

Comment: @vb4 `pass` does literally nothing (it's just a syntactic placeholder). With `pass` there, I would expect nothing to happen.

Comment: @Carcigenicate alright, understandable, I just assumed it would cause it to return to the beginning of the `while` loop.

Comment: @vb4 Then you're looking for `continue`, not `pass`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ah, thank you, although it doesn't seem to act any differently to `pass`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're testing that something is true in the files.  In that case, read the files to a variable and test the variables

```py
with open("iterations.txt","r") as f:
    iterations_text = f.read()

with open("dashes.txt", "r") as f:
   dashes_text = f.read()

did_the_bad_thing_happen = False

while restart == True:
    while count < 36:
        characterAdd = chars[random.randint(0,35)]
        if not characterAdd in array:
            array.append(characterAdd)
            count += 1
        else:
            pass
    tempArray = "".join(map(str,array))
    dashTemp = tempArray[0:11]
    dotTemp = tempArray[11:23]
    spaceTemp = tempArray[23:35]
    dashTemp = "".join(sorted(dashTemp))
    dotTemp = "".join(sorted(dotTemp))
    spaceTemp = "".join(sorted(spaceTemp))
    if array in iterations_text or dashTemp in dashes_text or ...:
        did_the_bad_thing_happen = True
        break  #  also, this might solve your problem!
```

If you're determined to go down your path, you should break out of the loop as soon as you close the filestream using `break` like in the above example.

Comment: This seems like a better way of going about it than my way, however when filling in the other file openings / readings I am met with the error `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list` on line `if array in iterations_text or dashTemp in dashes_text or dotTemp in dots_text or spaceTemp in spaces_text:`

Comment: you need to cast `array` as a string.  maybe `"".join(array)`